# App crashes with NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle'

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, xcode6.3

Everyone I'm working on a `iOS Static Library`. when I use this static library in sample app and run it, it crashes with below exception...

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D982246E-72D6-482F-8E1C-AE3D1BF37607/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/016193F2-36A3-492D-8E7B-CE560FACCF6D/TestApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'OptionsViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107385c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010701ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107385b9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000107d30171 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 552
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107b88718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000107b88d08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107b88f79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107b8940e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107bae297 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 633
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107bba3bf -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107bbaf0e -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107d05715 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107ad8a2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bcbeec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bcb36d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bcb3546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bc1f886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bc20a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bc210eb _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072b8ca7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072b8c00 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072aea33 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072ae366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b7e7a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000107a58900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    25  TestApp                0x0000000106a54bcf main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109b7f145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I know, generally this error mean that `OptionsViewController` xib file is not been included in this library/project but guess what? `OptionsViewController's` `.m` file present in `compile Sources` and `.h` and `.xib` file present there in copy files of `Build Phases` of library.

This library was working file with `Xcode 6.1`. The time I install `Xcode 6.3`. this crash came in to picture, now it is not working even in `Xcode 6.1`

Now I'm clueless why my sample app keep crashing. It has been 1 whole day, I have been struggling with this particular issue without any luck.

Any **guidance, clue, anything** would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

**App not able to find Resources, files, anything from Static Library.**
I have to include all `.h` , `.xibs` and `resources` files in to build face of sample app to make it work, which is not a right way to do it I feel.

Comment: Have you opened the .app file and double checked that the .xib file is really in there?

Comment: which method do you use to init the class ?

Comment: @DanieleCandotti `[[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsViewController" bundle:nil];` is the way I'm initialising this object.

Comment: @picciano yes! I can see this in the .app file. the path inside .app is `include/SDK/`

Comment: @picciano anything if you could figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[OptionsViewController class]]];` instead.